# How do you push a recently popped element from one stack to another?

Tags: java, stack

Say I have the following code:

```
public Stack s1;
public Stack s2;

//I want to take the top element from s1 and push it onto s2

s1.pop();

//Gather recently popped element and assign it a name.

s2.push(recentlyPopped);
```

Any ideas on how I would do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementations like `LinkedList` are preferable over Java's `Stack`, which extends the synchronized `Vector`.

Comment: @PaulBellora OP doesn't show why uses the `Stack`. Maybe it's for a Tower of Hanoi implementation or another homework.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It was just an FYI.

Answer (score 3):

The basic form would be

```
s2.push(s1.pop());
```

If you need to process the data from the 1st stack befor/after pushing it in the 2nd stack, you can use

```
YourClass yourClass = s1.pop();
//process yourClass variable...
s2.push(yourClass);
//more process to yourClass variable...
```

Remember to check that s1 isn't empty before using the `pop` method or else you could get an EmptyStackException.

```
if (!s1.isEmpty()) {
    s2.push(s1.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] inputs = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
Stack<String> stack1 = new Stack<String>();
Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<String>();
for (String input : inputs) {
  stack1.push(input);
}
System.out.println("stack1: " + stack1);
System.out.println("stack2: " + stack2);
stack2.push(stack1.pop());
System.out.println("stack1: " + stack1);
System.out.println("stack2: " + stack2);
```

The output will be:

```
stack1: [A, B, C, D, E]
stack2: []
stack1: [A, B, C, D]
stack2: [E]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other constraints which are not specified in question. One approach would be:

```
YourElementType elem = s1.pop();

s2.push(elem);
```